# Continuum Limit for this Sum

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter

Consider a sum of the form

$$
S=\sum_{\substack{k \\ k \neq k_0}} \frac{f(k)}{k-k_0},
$$

where $k$ is running over some countably infinite set of numbers and $f$ is a well behaved function, such that $S$ exists. In the problem I'm working on the $k$ are related to wavenumbers of electrons and I'm interested in a specific continuum limit of the sum.
I know that i need to transform the sum to an integral and multiply the integrand by a function $g(k)$ (that is known to me), that contains amongst other things the density of states for my problem.

Now i get confused about how to translate the condition $k \neq k_0$ into
"integral language", because simply ignoring the condition leads to a divergent integral.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to multiply by $g(k)$ before integrating, and see if the singularity goes away

Comment: E.g., [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform : is there a proof or good argument why the continuum limit of this sum is given by a principal value integral? It seems arbitrary to cut out the singularity in a symmetric way

Comment: If the sum is over $k$'s placed symmetrically around $k_0$, Cauchy principal value is quite a natural replacement of the sum.